# Android device user-friendly model name (e.g., Samsung Galaxy S4 instead of Samsung GT-I9505G)

Tags: android

The title says it all. Any help is greatly appreciated. I tried the code below, but it gives the user not-so-friendly model name.

```
    public String getDeviceName() {
      String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
      String model = Build.MODEL;
      if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return capitalize(model);
      } else {
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
      }
    }

    public String capitalize(String s) {
      if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return "";
      }
      char first = s.charAt(0);
      if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
        return s;
      } else {
        return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
      }
    }
```

For instance, instead of **Samsung GT-I9505G**, I would like to get **Samsung Galaxy S4**.

Thanks much!

Comment: There is no requirement that this name be available to developers, let alone in a consistent fashion.

Comment: I think you have no option other than to build your own database of model name -> nice name mappings. There's probably some already out there (a quick Google found this: https://github.com/meetup/android-device-names).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your reply. That's interesting. I've found many apps showing those device names that are really hard to read even for developers, not to mention ordinary users. I'm surprised there is no requirement or standard yet.

Comment: @AlexMDC Thank you, Alex. You're reading my mind:) I'm thinking of some sort of mapping now.

Comment: The alphanumeric code allows the model name to be much more specific with respect to features such as network type and band. It identifies the phone much more precisely than the simple ' Galaxy S4'

Comment: @NickT Sure, Nick. I agree. I'm developing an app that shows performance charts of different phone models, and just thought that users would appreciate more the nice simple form of 'Galaxy S4'.